# reading JSON, null

Tags: objective-c, json

Here's my JSON

```
{
"name": "abe",
}
```

and this is a part of my code

```
    self.fileRoot = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"name" ofType:@"json"];
    self.jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:self.fileRoot encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    self.jsonParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    self.dict = [self.jsonParser objectWithString:self.jsonString];    
    NSLog(@"\njsonString: %@\njsonParser: %@\ndict: %@\n", self.jsonString, self.jsonParser, self.dict);
```

the log is:

```
jsonString: {
    "name": "abe",
}
jsonParser: <SBJsonParser: 0x8d6b7f0>
dict: (null)
```

I have the problem that's why dict said "(null)"
I'm pretty sure this code used to work when I tested it last time(about 3 months ago)
Any suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't have a comma before a brace in JSON. Commas go _between_ elements of an array or object, but not at the end of the them.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I have edited it but it seems to change nothing. self.dict still said (null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the comma from the key value pair, since you just have a single name-value pair in json string

```
//convert string to NSData
NSString* str = @"{'name':'abe'}";
NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//create dictionary
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization
                        JSONObjectWithData: data
                        options:0
                        error:&error];

NSLog(@"Name: %@", dict[@"name"]);
```

Comment: This solves my problem >__<
Can you tell me why the code that used to work cause this issue?
By the way, thank you very much!!!